# MySQL Load not inserting All records from xml

Tags: mysql, load

I am using the following command to load record from xml file to mysql db. But everytime some records are inserted as null in the table.

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'xml_file_path' INTO TABLE table_name ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<column1>';
```

xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<column1>Brother</column1>
<column2>Alex</column2>
<column3>SONTOSH</column3>
---
---
</data>
```

How to avoid the null entry in the db?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

File: `data.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <column1>Brother</column1>
    <column2>Alex</column2>
    <column3>SONTOSH</column3>
</data>
```

SQL:

```sql
mysql> CREATE TABLE `data` (
    ->   `column1` VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `column2` VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `column3` VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> LOAD XML INFILE '/path/to/data.xml'
    -> INTO TABLE `data`
    -> ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<data>';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select `column1`, `column2`, `column3`
    -> from `data`;
+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Brother | Alex    | SONTOSH |
+---------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```